# Need help understanding E8 asm call instruction x86

Tags: assembly, x86, disassembly

I need a helping hand in order to understand the following assembly instruction. It seems to me that I am calling a address at someUnknownValue += 20994A?

```
E8 32F6FFFF - call std::_Init_locks::operator=+20994A
```

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Whatever you're using to obtain the disassembly is trying to be helpful, by giving the target of the call as an offset from some symbol that it knows about -- but given that the offset is so large, it's probably confused.

The actual target of the call can be calculated as follows:

- `E8` is a `call` with a relative offset.
- In a 32-bit code segment, the offset is specified as a signed 32-bit value.
- This value is in little-endian byte order.
- The offset is measured from the address of the following instruction.

e.g.

```
<some address>       E8 32 F6 FF FF         call <somewhere>
<some address>+5     (next instruction)
```

- The offset is `0xFFFFF632`.
- Interpreted as a signed 32-bit value, this is `-0x9CE`.
- The `call` instruction is at `<some address>` and is 5 bytes long; the next instruction is at `<some address> + 5`.
- So the target address of the call is `<some address> + 5 - 0x9CE`.

Comment: Tank you so much. Your example is spot on!

Comment: @Matthew
could the call instruction be more than 5 bytes long?  (In a x86 archi. can the next instric. be at <some address> + 6)? In what case?

Comment: @Rafa, call relative offset instruction is 5 bytes, because max relative offset must fit in 4 bytes. If the target is farther than 2**31 bytes away, `mov reg, imm64; call reg` is used.

Answer (score -2):

If you are analyzing the PE file with a disassembler, the disassembler might had given you the wrong code. Most malware writer uses insertion of E8 as anti-disassembly technique. You can verify if the codes above E8 are jump instructions where the jump location is after E8.