# c++ Pointer operation equivalent with ReadProcessMemory

Tags: c++, pointers, readprocessmemory

I need to read a program's memory from a different application.
I have the whole process and application 'connection' in place.

I have a function that searches for a pattern in the memory of the opened process, and that thanks to a signature returns a valid entry point to the function I'm interested in.

Problem is, the assembly instruction that leads me to the data (which I can't find through an offset or signature), is the following:

```
H5Calc.exe+12DDC5B - E8 10F1FFFF           - call H5Calc.exe+12DCD70
```

I've searched around and found that this might serve my purpose:

```
return (MainClass*) *(DWORD*) PatternPointer;
```

but the problem is that the line above would work if using 'injection', and I'm using ReadProcessMemory since I'm not allowed to do so.

So, can somebody help 'translating' the

```
(MainClass*) *(DWORD*) PatternPointer;
```

pointer operation into a ReadProcessMemory call, considering the assembly instruction?
Given that I'm opening from another application, I don't have access to the H5Calc memory area if not with ReadProcessMemory (which I can call regularly for other operations).

Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: `ReadProcessMemory(hProc, (void *)0x12DCD70, &data, sizeof data, NULL);`, maybe? (assuming that `data` is a `DWORD` or a pointer, of course.)

Comment: I agree that seems logic, but I can't figure how to get `'12dcd70'` out from the `'e8 10f1ffff'` nor from the `1sddc5b <= this one the address i get to from the signature` :(

Comment: it's on the right side of the code you posted...

Comment: truly, but that's debug information from the debugger. While using my pattern finding routine, that information is unknown and I only have access to the `e8 10f1ffff0` byte sequence.

Comment: in that case, [here's how you can do that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10376787/need-help-understanding-e8-asm-call-instruction-x86).

Comment: Please make an answer out of your comment so that I can accept it and close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the actual address as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10376787/need-help-understanding-e8-asm-call-instruction-x86), i. e. you take the address of the instruction following the jump, which is

```
0x12DDC5B + 5 = 0x12DDC60
```

then you take the offset which is a 32-bit little endian 2's complement signed integer, so

```
"0x10 0xF1 0xFF 0xFF" = 0xFFFFF110 - 0x100000000 = -0xEF0
```

Then you add the offset to the base address computed above to obtain

```
0x12DDC60 + (-0xEF0) = 0x12DCD70
```

In C, this would look something like:

```
unsigned char *jmp_ptr = (unsigned char *)0x12DDC5B;
int offset; // or use ptrdiff_t if it's 32 bits wide
ReadProcessMemory(hProc, jmp_ptr + 1, &offset, sizeof offset, NULL);
unsigned char *target_ptr = jmp_ptr + 5 + offset;
```

(apply stylistic mash-ups to obtain C++ code. Also check the return value of the function, etc.)

You can now feed the resulting address to another call to `ReadProcessMemory()` in order to obtain the pointer to the instance:

```
MainClass *instance = NULL;
ReadProcessMemory(hProc, target_ptr, &instance, sizeof instance, NULL);
```

Comment: This works perfectly, however I now have what seems a similar issue:


`H5Calc.exe+989E2A - 8B 0D 888C1D03        - mov ecx,[H5Calc.exe+2DD8C88]`
By debugging memory, I think that should lead me to 002BC768, but the above logic doesn't seem to apply. (damn can't we put line breaks in comments?). I realize the MOV instruction supports both values and addresses on the right side, yet I fail to understand how is `888C1D03` to be interpreted.

Comment: @Alphacockroach I guess the `mov` instruction doesn't have the same binary encoding scheme that the `call` instruction has.

Answer (score 0):

You could use shared memory between processes.  If you want to know how to do this I can post some code.  The Windows API uses CreateFileMapping() and MapViewOfFile().  Then both processes can see the same memory.

Comment: thanks but I don't need actual communication between the processes right now. I just needed to understand how to interpret the ASM and be able to use readprocessmemory to perform the required operations.